# Можно ли в одном case использовать несколько значений?

Tags: c#, case

Говорю именно о case.

> ```
> int dayNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
>     switch (dayNumber) 
>     case 1||8://значение равное 1 или 8 
>         Console.WriteLine("Понедельник");
>         break;
>     case 2||9||10://значение 2,9 или 10  ...
>     default:
>         Console.WriteLine("Воскресенье");
>         break; }
> ```

Comment: можно, но не так

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [C# 9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements) можно делать так:

```
switch(myvar)
{
    case 2 or 5:
        // ...
        break;

    case 7 or 12:
        // ...
        break;
    // ...
}
```

А если это использовать совместно с [Switch expressions из C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) можно делать:

```
static string Testy(int dayNumber) => dayNumber switch
{
    3 or 4 or 5 => "111",
    6 or 7 or 8 => "222",
    9 or 10 or 11 => "333",
    12 or 1 or 2 => "444",
    _ => "Какая-то ерунда",
};
```

Comment: Благодарю Алексей Шиманский

Answer (score 3):

Например так

```
var myValue = 0;

switch (myValue)
{
    case 1: 
    case 2: 
    case 3:
        Console.WriteLine(myValue);
        break;

    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        Console.WriteLine(myValue*2);
        break;
        
    default: 
        Console.WriteLine(myValue*10);
        break;
}
```